# Using Javascript if && to check if element has one class but not another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use javascript (not jquery) to find IF an element with class 'button' on click does NOT have the 'active' class. If this is true i have another 3 if statements to check weather the same clicked button has one of the mentioned classes below. I cant work out where i need to put the initial IF statement looking for the active class.

Here is what I have so far

```
for (var b = 0; b < button.length; b++) {
    button[b].addEventListener('click', function () {

        //IF ELEMENT DOES NOT HAVE CLASS 'ACTIVE' RUN THE BELOW IF STATEMENTS ALSO

        if (this.classList.contains('to--section-1')) {
            //do something

        } else if (this.classList.contains('to--section-2')) {
            //do something

        } else if (this.classList.contains('to--section-3')) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT

```
var transition = document.querySelector('.transition__overlay');
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.sections');
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__link');
var navHome = document.querySelector('.navigation__link--home');
var navKenya = document.querySelector('.navigation__link--kenya');
var navBotswana = document.querySelector('.navigation__link--botswana');
var navSouthAfrica = document.querySelector('.navigation__link--south-africa');
var home = document.querySelector('.home');
var kenya = document.querySelector('.kenya');
var botswana = document.querySelector('.botswana');
var upNextKenya = document.querySelector('.up__next--kenya');
var upNextBotswana = document.querySelector('.up__next--botswana');
var upNextSouthAfrica = document.querySelector('.up__next--south-africa');
var toHome = document.querySelectorAll('.to--home');
var toKenya = document.querySelectorAll('.to--kenya');
var toBotswana = document.querySelectorAll('.to--botswana');
var upNext = document.querySelector('.up__next');
var upNextBox = document.querySelectorAll('.up__next__box');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
var active = document.querySelectorAll('.active');

for (var b = 0; b < button.length; b++) {
    button[b].addEventListener('click', function () {
 //IF ELEMENT DOES NOT HAVE CLASS 'ACTIVE' RUN THE BELOW IF STATEMENTS ALSO
        if (this.classList.contains('to--home')) {
            sectionChange();
            home.classList.add('active');
            navHome.classList.add('active');
            upNextKenya.classList.add('active');
        } else if (this.classList.contains('to--kenya')) {
            sectionChange();
            kenya.classList.add('active');
            navKenya.classList.add('active');
            upNextBotswana.classList.add('active');
        } else if (this.classList.contains('to--botswana')) {
            sectionChange();
            botswana.classList.add('active');
            navBotswana.classList.add('active');
            upNextSouthAfrica.classList.add('active');
        }
        sectionTransition();
        upNextTransition();
    });
}

//Functions

function sectionChange() {
    for (var s = 0; s < sections.length; s++) {
        sections[s].classList.remove('active');
    }
    for (var l = 0; l < navLinks.length; l++) {
        navLinks[l].classList.remove('active');
    }
    for (var u = 0; u < upNextBox.length; u++) {
        upNextBox[u].classList.remove('active');
    }
}

function sectionTransition() {
    transition.classList.add('transition__overlay--active');
    setTimeout(function () {
        transition.classList.remove('transition__overlay--active');
    }, 1000);
}

function upNextTransition() {
    upNext.classList.add('up__next--hide');
    setTimeout(function () {
        upNext.classList.remove('up__next--hide');
    }, 1600);
}
```

SOLUTION

I have found the solution by adding if (!this.classList.contains('active')) at the top and nesting the other if statements.

```
for (var b = 0; b < button.length; b++) {
    button[b].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (!this.classList.contains('active')) {
            if (this.classList.contains('to--home')) {
                sectionChange();
                home.classList.add('active');
                navHome.classList.add('active');
                upNextKenya.classList.add('active');
            } else if (this.classList.contains('to--kenya')) {
                sectionChange();
                kenya.classList.add('active');
                navKenya.classList.add('active');
                upNextBotswana.classList.add('active');
            } else if (this.classList.contains('to--botswana')) {
                sectionChange();
                botswana.classList.add('active');
                navBotswana.classList.add('active');
                upNextSouthAfrica.classList.add('active');
            }
            sectionTransition();
            upNextTransition();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why can't you use `if(!this.classList.contains('active')){  }`?

Comment: Put the argument e in `button[b].addEventListener('click', function (e) {` and then: `if(e.target not in document.getElementsByClassName("active"))`

Comment: @Attersson that is just not true. Within  callback that isn't arrow function `this` is the element. In other words `this === event.currentTarget`

Comment: i have updated my initial post with my full javascript code. Sorry if i sounded confusing

Comment: @Attersson yes I'm sure as I said so long as it ***isn't*** an arrow function

Comment: worked out the solution by adding the if (!this.classList.contains('active')) at the top and nesting the other if statements. Seems to do the job fine

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by adding if (!this.classList.contains('active')) at the top and nesting the other if statements.

```
for (var b = 0; b < button.length; b++) {
    button[b].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (!this.classList.contains('active')) {
            if (this.classList.contains('to--home')) {
                sectionChange();
                home.classList.add('active');
                navHome.classList.add('active');
                upNextKenya.classList.add('active');
            } else if (this.classList.contains('to--kenya')) {
                sectionChange();
                kenya.classList.add('active');
                navKenya.classList.add('active');
                upNextBotswana.classList.add('active');
            } else if (this.classList.contains('to--botswana')) {
                sectionChange();
                botswana.classList.add('active');
                navBotswana.classList.add('active');
                upNextSouthAfrica.classList.add('active');
            }
            sectionTransition();
            upNextTransition();
        }
    });
}
```